# Reading file data into two arrays (not array lists)

Tags: java, arrays, string, delimiter

I have a file:

```
A,0.3
B,0.1
C,0.2
 ...
```

And I want the resulting arrays to be of the form:

```
String[] symbols = {A, B, C, ...}

Double[] frequencies = {0.3, 0.1, 0.2, ...}
```

I have figured this out using ArrayList (.add() is nice), but after some design decisions, I want the data in regular arrays. Obviously my implementation below does not work, but it's the closest I've come:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        count ++;             // Number of lines incremented

        String[] parts;
        parts = r.split(",");

        // Store symbols into its own array
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
                syms[i] = parts[0];

        // Store frequencies into its own array
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
                freqs[i] = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
        }
```

Count keeps track of the amount of scanned lines (true while conditions), which at first seemed unnecessary to me, but I'm trying it now. Hence the help. Thanks.

Comment: how do you figure out the size of the arrays before hand?

Comment: Try use collections because when you don't know number of lines in file, using array is not a programming practice

Comment: what array can do and array list can not do?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I suppose counting the number of lines read would do the trick. The file does not change the format listed

Comment: Is it possible to read the amount of lines in the file, then go back and read the rest of the data?

Comment: No, you need to read the whole file twice.  If for some strange reason you want the data to be in arrays, it is still going to be easier and cleaner code to put into an ArrayList initially, and then convert `toArray` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**    i have created an array of 5  but the good procedure is to use array-list to increase decrease  the size of array dynamically

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String[] myArray;
double[] doubleArray = new double[5];
String[] strArray= new String[5];

     int inc1=0;
     int inc2=0;
     FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("test.txt");
     Scanner s= new Scanner(fileReader);

     while(s.hasNext()){
           myArray= s.next().split(",");
       // to store double values
    for (String getStr: myArray) {
        if(isDouble(getStr)==true){
            doubleArray[inc1]= Double.parseDouble(getStr);
            inc1++;
        }
       // to store string values
        else {
            strArray[inc2]=getStr;
            inc2++;
        }
  }
  }

      for(String ss : strArray){
             System.out.println("str value-> : "+ ss);
         }
         for(Double nnn : doubleArray){
             System.out.println("double value-> : " + nnn);
         }

      fileReader.close();

}
```

**check its convertible or not if its than it sends true else false**

```
 public static boolean isDouble( String input ) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(input );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Testfile contains:**

```
A,0.3 
B,0.1 
C,0.2
d,0.4 
e,0.5
```

**output :**

```
str value-> : A
str value-> : B
str value-> : C
str value-> : d
str value-> : e
double value-> : 0.3
double value-> : 0.1
double value-> : 0.2
double value-> : 0.4
double value-> : 0.5
```

hope answered the question if its useful than vote up

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works well if I read the lines beforehand and pass that in as the size of the array.